# opencart 2.3.0.2 htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, redirect

I tried the other solutions I found online but didn't workout. 
My htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 ^abc https://www.example.com/abc-products


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I was expecting `example.com/abc` url redirect to `example.com/abc-products` but it is redirecting to `example.com/abc-products?_route_=abc`

I also, tried the below ways

```
Redirect 301 ^abc https://www.example.com/abc-products
Redirect 301 ^/abc /abc-products
Redirect 301 /abc /abc-products
```

But the result is always `https://www.example.com/abc-products?_route_=abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after

`RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]`

add

```
 RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /abc-products/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for the code. It is giving me Internal server error for entire site.

Comment: Have edited the code, I provided previously - hopefully this new code will work

Comment: Hey Dave, that worked but I rewrite rule format didn't work for me. I had to change it to RewriteRule ^abc /abc-products [R=301,NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

i thik you should try this code. 100% working.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/abc-products
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If You have not working well. you let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide an explanation on why this code should be working.

Comment: Hey Mujahid Bhoraniya, thanks for the code. It is giving me Internal server error.

Comment: now you can copy my code and paste your htaccess. i think working now. i changed this line - Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/abc-products

Comment: I tried that line and still see the 500 Error. Even I tried with 'RewriteEngine On' but no use.